# Find total number of Increasing Subsequences of given length

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subsequence

Given an array of numbers and **question** is to find **total number** of *Increasing sub-sequences of length* **lis-1**, where **lis** is the length of `Largest Increasing sub-sequence` of that given array.

**Example:** Suppose the array is `5 6 3 4 7 8`. Here, **lis =  4**. So, **lis-1 = 3**. Therefore, the total number of sub-sequences are `8` and  given below:

```
5 6 7
5 6 8
3 4 7 
3 4 8
3 7 8
6 7 8
5 7 8
4 7 8
```

Can someone give me an idea for this algorithm, i'm not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a dynamic programming approach. For each point in the sequence, keep an array holding the number of subsequences terminating at that point of length k.

At each point you can work out the contents of its array from the contents of arrays to its left and the corresponding points of the subsequence: add in array values from points to the left with sequence values less than the current values as e.g. count[currentPos][k+1] += count[leftPos][k].

At the end the highest non-zero position in the array marks the position of the largest increasing subsequence and the value just below that gives the count of increasing subsequences of length one shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem even without using dynamic programming.Assuming elements of the array are unique(you can extend the idea further for duplicates),Idea is that you maintain a set (which stores unique elements in increasing order) and fill this set while you are processing array elements.If you can extend the set by current element (means current element is the biggest element seen so far)then you append this element to the end of the set otherwise current element will replace one of the set element which position will be where you are fitting current element.In this way keep track of set when its length is lis-1 and increase the counter.
I hope that helps, if you need any more explanation then let me know.

Comment: But this sounds like, naive method and also very costly in terms of time. Don't you think.

Comment: No, insertion ,deletion and searching in set is O(logn) and you are only doing one search/update/insertion for each new element  to be processed in the set.So overall O(nlogn).

Comment: OK i got it but it would be better, you add few points and put your procedure point-wise.